# Search for string in sed after ocurrence of another string

Tags: sed

The input file I have looks like this

```
Topic1
Some text
Topic2
Some text
Topic3
Some text
```

I need to go to Topic2 and then replace "Some text" with "Actual input"

The following script works

```
/Topic2/,/Topic/ {
/Some text/c
Actual input
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this. I was hoping the following will work but it does not.

```
/Topic2/ {
/Some text/c
Actual input
}
```

Update : Should have made it clearer. Am only looking for sed based solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/Topic2/,/Topic/{//!d;/Topic2/a\bla\nbla\nbla' -e '}' file
```

or:

```
sed -e '/Topic2/,/Topic/{//!d;/Topic2/r fileb' -e '}' filea
```

or using Bash:

```
sed $'/Topic2/,/Topic/{//!d;/Topic2/a\\bla\\nbla\\nbla\n}' file
```

EDIT:

```
sed $'/Topic2/{:a;n;/Some text/!ba;c\\Actual input\n}' file
```

Comment: Looks like "range" (/start_range/,/end_range/ ) is the only way to do this. The second example I have given will not work.

Answer (score 1):

how about with awk?

```
awk 'p&&/Topic/{p=0}/Topic2/{p=1}p{gsub(/Some text/,"foo\nbar\nbla\nline")}7' file
```

above I used a multiple line replacement as example, the output with your input would be:

```
Topic1
Some text
Topic2
foo
bar
bla
line
Topic3
```

you can pass the replacement string to awk as shell variable, so that the awk one-liner would be flexible. like:

```
kent$  r="a
b
c"

kent$  awk -v rep="$r" 'p&&/Topic/{p=0}/Topic2/{p=1}p{gsub(/Some text/,rep)}7' f  
Topic1
Some text
Topic2
a
b
c
Topic3
Some text
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `gnu awk` solution:

```
awk -v RS="Topic[0-9]*" 'f=="Topic2" {$0="\nActual input\n"} NR>1{print f,$0} {f=RT}' file
Topic1
Some text

Topic2
Actual input

Topic3
Some text
```